# Script does not run under cron but runs manually

Tags: linux, cron

I have a script that a developer wrote for me which performs various functions mainly related to ffmpeg. When I run the script manually using

```
sh /home/site/rawvids/encode.sh > /home/site/rawvids/log.txt
```

The script runs fine but when it runs through cron it fails with error code 127

Any ideas?

`ls -l` on the script shows:

> -rwxrwxrwx 1 site nobody 3786 Jul 23 17:07 /home/site/rawvids/encode.sh*

Comment: a) different PATH used by cron? b) permissions on the script keeping cron from running it?

Comment: `ls -l /home/zavids/rawvids/encode.sh` and add the output to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error 127 means "command not found".
It is likely that you run in the script some commands that are not in the of `cron` (you can see what cron's PATH is, if you look at `/etc/crontab`).

You can check your current PATH in the shell:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

And then copy this PATH to the beginning of the script:

```
PATH=...
```

Instead of `...` you must write the line that you've got earlier (using `echo $PATH`).

Also check if you have shebang line `#!/bin/sh` at the beginning of the script. It is import if you start script without `sh` in the command line.

Also it would be great if you could show us the line from `/etc/crontab` that runs the script.

Comment: /usr/local/jdk/bin:/opt/jdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin

Comment: Which part of that would I add to the beginning of the script?

Comment: The shebang line is at the beginning of the script and the line from etc/crontab is as follows

Comment: 52 19 * * * sh /home/zavids/rawvids/encode.sh > /home/zavids/rawvids/log.txt

Comment: This is the path in cron PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

Comment: If this line from `/etc/crontab`, it is incorrect. You must add username (`root` or `zavidis`) before the commandline; `52 19 * * * root sh ...`

Comment: Tried that and this time the script did not run and nothing was added to log file

Comment: Cron entry looks as follows; 26 14 * * * root sh /home/zavids/rawvids/encode.sh > /home/zavids/rawvids/log.txt

Comment: can you please add such string (just to check cron): `* * * * * root date >> /tmp/date.log` and check the file `/tmp/date.log`?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I added that entry and the date.log file is empty

Comment: That is strange. In what file have you add the line?

Comment: Yes, but there are many crontabs in system (global and users'). And they have different syntax. Did you add the line to `/etc/crontab` or to the users' crontab?

Comment: I logged in with root and then added it via crontab -e

Comment: Then it is not `/etc/crontab`. Please run `crontab -e` and remove `root` from the line you've added. The line must look so: `* * * * * date >> /tmp/date.log`

Comment: Did that and now it's logging. Sun Jul 29 17:14:01 SAST 2012

Comment: Ok, super! Now can you please (1) write this line `sh /home/zavids/rawvids/encode.sh >> /home/zavids/rawvids/log.txt` instead of `date >> /tmp/date.log`? And (2) add this line `date >> /tmp/date.log` to the first line of the `/home/zavids/rawvids/encode.sh` just to check if the line will be executed (if it will, that means that script executes also).

Comment: Ok the date was added to date.log and nothing was writted to log.txt. Thanks for all your help btw :)

Comment: Ok, that is super! That means that something is wrong with your script. Can you show it at pastebin for example?

Comment: Ok, the script is good; can you please also add `2>&1` to the end of the command: `sh /home/zavids/rawvids/encode.sh >> /home/zavids/rawvids/log.txt 2>&1` and check log.txt once again?

Comment: But please bear in mind running the script manually liked this before worked. It's only when it runs via cron that it does not work

Comment: all works good as you can see; the results must be in `/home/zavids/www/vfiles`

Comment: Yes it works but not in cron. That's the problem. The script has always run manually but not in cron

Comment: I mean that logs that you sent me, they were from script that was started from cron?

Comment: Please run the command `sh /home/zavids/rawvids/encode.sh >> /home/zavids/rawvids/log.txt 2>&1` from `cron`!

Comment: It worked this time. I was scratching my head as to why this should be and I realised that yesterday I changed the permissions on the source folder to 777 due to another issue I was having. Do you think this could have resolved it?

Comment: yes it could, when the owner of the target directory is not the owner of the `crontab`. If it is the same, then not, there must be another reason.

Comment: I just had a proper look at the log file and it's still failing. Here is the output

Comment: You will see that it looks as if the ffmpeg and mp4box commands cannot be found but only when run from cron

Comment: can you please run `which ffmpeg` and say the result?

Comment: add `PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` to the beginning of your script (to the second line).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14683/discussion-between-michael-farah-and-igor-chubin)

Comment: Just for anyone else viewing this question. Igor solved my problem by having me add PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH to the second line of the script

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're either depending on an environment variable which isn't set for cron (I'm not sure if cron uses any?) or the permissions cron is running under are wrong. If you're piping the output like that in the cron version, does it get any output?

Comment: I'm not really that experienced with cron or linux so don't know but I do get output as follows;

Answer (score 0):

same ..., well i just can stand these path issues , i set up a symbolic link to the ffprobe path or whatever is missing , something like

`ln -s /usr/local/bin/ffprobe /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ffprobe`